# Get active Applications Size in Android

Tags: android

I want to show the size of active application in android . How can I do this ?

I have seen the following code but it shows error .

```
 PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();

Method getPackageSizeInfo = pm.getClass().getMethod(
    "getPackageSizeInfo", String.class, IPackageStatsObserver.class);

getPackageSizeInfo.invoke(pm, "com.android.mms",
    new IPackageStatsObserver.Stub() {

        @Override
        public void onGetStatsCompleted(PackageStats pStats, boolean succeeded)
            throws RemoteException {

            Log.i(TAG, "codeSize: " + pStats.codeSize);
        }
    });
```

Guys , plz help me in finding the size of installed apps .

Comment: What is the actual problem you are having?  Make sure that your application has the `android.permission.GET_PACKAGE_SIZE` permission in order to do make this call.

Comment: My code shows error for "IPackageStatsObserver"

Comment: yap . I agree . But I can not download IPackageStatsObserver.class .